# Qual è la differenza tra "metterci" e "volerci"?

Tags: verbs, difference, particles

Salve a tutti,

vorrei capire la differenza tra questi due verbi, qualcuno mi può aiutare per favore?

Ho fatto un po' di ricerca e mi sono resa conto che entrambi possono indicare "il tempo".

Ad esempio: "il treno ci mette venti minuti" ma "ci vogliono venti minuti in treno".

Dopo aver osservato qualche esempio, mi pare di capire che la differenza sia nel soggetto (il treno-soggetto "ci mette", ma i minuti-soggetto "ci vogliono"). È giusto il mio ragionamento? Come spiegare ad uno studente straniero la differenza?

Altro esempio:

*A volte Lucia ci:

1- mette un po' a capire.

2- vuole un po' a capire.*

In questo caso basterebbe aggiungere una "A" alla frase (*A volte **a** Lucia ci vuole un po' a capire*) per avere una frase corretta con "ci vuole". Senza quella preposizione però, la frase è corretta solo con "ci mette".

Grazie!

Comment: Il tuo ragionamento sulla differenza _metterci/volerci_ mi sembra corretto. La frase "ci vogliono venti minuti..." è equivalente a "sono necessari venti minuti..."; la particella "ci" è diventata non scindibile dal verbo e ne ha mutato il significato. Puoi trovare qui una bella discussione http://aulalingue.scuola.zanichelli.it/benvenuti/2010/12/02/la-forma-impersonale/
A mio parere la frase _A volte a Lucia ci vuole un po' a capire_ può essere utilizzata nella lingua parlata, ma la ritengo troppo convoluta e sembra addirittura essere un esempio di anacoluto :D

Answer (score 4):

> **Volerci** significa: "*essere necessario*", "*occorrere*" , molto spesso quello che è necessario viene sottinteso, può essere tempo, fatica, denaro ecc, per questo di solito il verbo è coniugato alla terza persona singolare o plurale. Spesso è sottintesa la parola "tempo".

**Esempi**: *per un vestito ci vogliono tre metri di stoffa; per una moto così ci vorranno circa diecimila euro; ci vuole molto* [sottint. tempo] *per arrivare fin là?; c’è voluto molto* [sottint. sforzo, fatica, insistenza] *per convincerlo; ci vuole un bel coraggio a presentarsi in quel modo!; ci vorrebbe una persona come te al suo posto; è proprio la persona che ci vuole; ci vuol pazienza!; Mi ci vorrebbe proprio una bella vacanza!*

> La forma verbale "**metterci**", oltre che con il significato di "*mettere in qualcosa*" (ci devi mettere un po’ di sale), viene spesso usata sottointendendo la parola "tempo", significa perciò "*impiegare un determinato tempo*".

**Esempi**: *il treno ci mette due ore; ce ne hai messo di tempo!; ci ha messo sei giorni la letterina ad arrivare*.